# Problems with Backpropagation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, backpropagation, perceptron

I'm visualizing a Perceptron with Backpropagation for a computer science assignment, but for some reason with XOR training data it always trains to output values close to zero for any inputs and i cant find the problem, here is the code: https://gitlab.com/OmegaRogue/neuralnetworkunity
Edit: the relevant code:
DisplayNn.cs

```cs
private void LearnStep()
    {
        _synapses.ForEach(synapse => synapse.Learn());
        _neurons.ForEach(neuron => neuron.Learn());
        error = CalculateError();
        iterations++;
        GraphManager.Graph.Plot("Error",
                                error,
                                Color.green);
    }
private float CalculateError()
    {
        return _outLayer.Sum(a => Math.Abs(a.error));
    }
```

Neuron.cs

```
public void Calculate()
    {
        if (!_initialized)
            return;


        switch (type)
        {
            case ENeuronType.Hidden:
            case ENeuronType.Output:
                var result =
                    NeuralMaths.Transfer[(int) nn.transferFunction](NeuralMaths.Input
                                                                        [
                                                                          (int) nn
                                                                             .inputFunction](inputSynapses
                                                                                                .Select(synapse =>
                                                                                                            synapse
                                                                                                               .Data)));
                value      = result.value;
                derivative = result.derivative;
                break;
            case ENeuronType.Input:
                value = input;
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }

        switch (type)
        {
            case ENeuronType.Output:
            {
                error = NeuralMaths.Error[(int)nn.errorFunction](value, nn.CurrentData.output[0]);
                delta = error * derivative;
                break;
            }
            case ENeuronType.Hidden:
            {
                var sum = outputSynapses.Sum(synapse => synapse.output.delta * synapse.weight);
                delta = derivative * sum;
                break;
            }
            case ENeuronType.Input:
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }
```

Synapse.cs

```
private void Start()
    {
        var numberOfInputConnections = output.inputSynapses.Count;
        var coefficient              = 1/ math.sqrt(numberOfInputConnections);
        coefficient = coefficient == 0 ? 1 : coefficient;


        weight = coefficient * Random.Range(-0.5f, 0.5f);

    }
private void Update()
    {
        if(!initialized)
            return;

        var position = input.transform.position;
        angle                     = Vector2.SignedAngle(input.Right -position, output.Left -position);
        transform.position        = Vector3.Lerp(input.Right, output.Left, .5f);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle);
        graphicTransform.SetSizeWithCurrentAnchors(RectTransform.Axis.Horizontal, Vector2.Distance(input.Right, output.Left));

        weightDelta = -nn.learningRate * output.delta * input.value;

        weightLabel.text          = $"{weight}";

        synapseGraphic.color = weight < 0 ? Color.red * math.abs(weight):Color.green * math.abs(weight);

    }

    public void Learn()
    {
        weight += weightDelta;
    }
```

NeuralMaths.cs

```
#region Error

    private static float SquaredError(float predictedOutput, float targetOutput) =>
        math.pow(predictedOutput - targetOutput, 2);

    private static float AbsoluteError(float predictedOutput, float targetOutput) =>
        math.abs(predictedOutput - targetOutput);

    #endregion
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code *in the question*, not merely linked off-site.  Your question will become useless for future readers once the code at the link changes or disappears.  Also, people are generally less willing to look through an entire project.  Share the relevant code with us, please.

Comment: Done, I added the most relevant parts of the most relevant files